# Как правильно продублировать элементы, соответствующие заданному параметру, из одного списка в другой?

Tags: c++, список

Нужно реализовать функцию, которая будет из одного списка выбирать структуру, в которoй `tourism->hotel_status == status`, и записывать ее в другой список. Сам изначальный список хранится в `begin`. `print` выводит список на экран. В данном случае не выводит вообще ничего. Список `status_of_hotel_sort` так и остается равен `NULL`.

Что я делаю не так?

```
void status_of_hotel(List* begin, int status)
{
    List* status_of_hotel = begin;
    List* status_of_hotel_sort = NULL;

    while (status_of_hotel)
    {
        if (status_of_hotel->tourism.hotel_status == status)
        {
            status_of_hotel_sort = status_of_hotel;
            status_of_hotel_sort = status_of_hotel->next;
            status_of_hotel = status_of_hotel->next;
        }
        else
        {
            status_of_hotel = status_of_hotel->next;
        }
    }

    print(status_of_hotel_sort);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала покажу два огреха.

```
status_of_hotel_sort = status_of_hotel;
status_of_hotel_sort = status_of_hotel->next;
```

Что вы хотели получить этими двумя присваиваниями? Второе просто затирает первое, нет?

```
    status_of_hotel=status_of_hotel->next;
}
else status_of_hotel=status_of_hotel->next;
```

Ну, это мелочь... и все же - не проще не дублировать код, а просто вынести его из `if-else` и написать один раз?

А в результате вы просто записываете в переменную `status_of_hotel_sort` указатель на элемент списка, следующий за последним найденным. Если последний элемент списка подходит под ваше условие - в `status_of_hotel_sort` будет `NULL`, потому что именно такое значение поля `next` у последнего элемента списка.

Зачем вам вообще создание нового **списка**, если вы его все равно при выходе из функции теряете? При этом получая (если таки сумеете сделать) утечки памяти?

Comment: Ага. Ошибку уловил. В какую сторону копать понял. Но вот что по-поводу нового списка не так, и как избежать этой утечки не понял. Мне нужна функция которая отберет из списка элементы соответсвующие переданному в аргементе условию tourism->hotel_status, и выведет на экран только эти элементы. Поэтому и хотел реализовать через временный список. Что бы в него их все отобрать.

Comment: @V.Rotenberh Так вы просто идите по списку тем циклом `while`, что у вас есть, только вместо всех телодвижений по созданию нового списка (старый же надо сохранить? Значит, надо каждый отобранный элемент *скопировать*, т.е. выделить память (!) и вставить в новый список...) просто сразу выводите его - этот найденный элемент - на экран.